# Scope issue with for loops

Tags: perl, for-loop, hash, split, scope

I am new to perl, and am having some scope or syntax issues.

I am trying to write a piece of code that reads lines from a file, splits them up at a certain delimiter into two pieces, and then stores each half as a key value pair in a hash. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my @config_pairs;
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp ($row);
  push (@config_pairs, $row);
}

my %config_data;
for my $pair (@config_pairs) {
  my ($key, $value) = split(/\s*=\s*/, $pair);
  %config_data{$key} = $value;
}

for my $k (%config_data) {
  print "$k is %config_data{$k}";
}
```

When I try and run this I get:

```
$ perl test_config_reader.pl --config.txt
"my" variable %config_data masks earlier declaration in same scope at test_email_reader.pl line 22.
syntax error at test_config_reader.pl line 19, near "%config_data{"
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at test_email_reader.pl line 19.
Execution of test_config_reader.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Clearly I don't understand how perl works yet.

Comment: Unless you need the `@config_pairs` later, you should read and split in one loop, saving space.

Comment: Maybe: `my %config_data = map { chomp; split /\s*=\s*/ } <$fh>;`? But I'm not sure that'll help a newcomer to perl "grok" it :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes that would be much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick note: Perl is a context based language. Your line "%config_data{$key} = $value;" is using the modulus sign, which implies that in this context "%config_data{$key}' is going to be a map, when in reality it is a scalar. (A scalar into which you are inserting $value.)

If you change your '%' to a '$' that line will become functionally correct. Whether this will fix your other issues I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm getting different messages when running the script:

```
Can't modify key/value hash slice in list assignment at ./1.pl line 19, near "$value;"
Global symbol "$key" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $key"?) at ./1.pl line 23.
Execution of ./1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

To refer to a single hash value, change the sigil from `%` to `$` (think "plural" versus "singular"):

```
$config_data{$key} = $value;
# ...
print "$k is $config_data{$k}";
```

Also, `$k` and `$key` are different variables (you seem to have fixed this in the meantime).

To iterate over a hash, use [keys](http://p3rl.org/keys):

```
for my $k (keys %config_data) {
```

Otherwise, you'll loop over the values, too.

Comment: One of the biggest "gotchas" with perl - the sigil denotes what you're expecting to get _out_. So `@array` is a list of values. `$array[1]` is a single scalar, as is `$hash{'some_key'}`.

Comment: @Sobrique: That's why it's gone in Perl6.

Comment: @Sobrique: No need to hurry :)

Comment: Might want to mention that `for my $k (%config_data) {` probably needs `keys` in there too.

Comment: @Sobrique thanks for the explanation of why this worked. Makes a lot more sense now!